# (Symfony2) Split / Group recurrent template and controller functions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a backend for a small project management tool based on Symfony2, Doctrine etc.

I have some outputs, which are on every page the same, like userlists, loglists. All this stuff is outputted on every page.

Currently I have in every controller the code to output it. So I have one and the same code in every of my controller. Also the same stuff in the templates.

Is there a possibility to outsorce these code fragments?

My wish is to have these parts, which are recurrent, placed in one single file - the PHP code placed in one file like "global functions" and the twig stuff maybe in a parent template, like the base.html.twig template.

How can I manage that to get some sort of tidyup in my code?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Marvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it is said in the [best practices for Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html), controllers should respect the pattern *facade*. This means that all your business code shouldn't be in your controllers. You're gonna ask me: "so where?".

Symfony2 provides a great way to develop big OOP architecture thanks to its dependency injection mechanism. It uses [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) (pattern SOA). You should use one service for each technical/functionnal identifiable part of your business code. The dependency injection help you to keep low coupled classes in order to have a more maintenable, scalable and testable application.

I think you already use some services like this in your controller:

```
$this->get('doctrine');
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I correctly understood you, I should outsorce all parts which I often need into services and just includes the service into my code? Sounds good - I will have a look into the service-topic. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes that's right! All Symfony2 works around services. Your Symfony2's codes will be really better if you learn to work with them. Moreover, you will see that it is so much more interesting to develop like that because you can do some nice architectures.

Answer (score 1):

May be another appraoch would be craeting a [TwigExtension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) and create a function, and use it (them) in templates:

final code in twig:

```
<div>
   {{ userlists() }}

   or 

   {{ userlogs() }}
</div>
```